# Apache Httpclient redirect with original query parameters

Tags: java, httpclient

Say I use `HttpClient` to send a GETrequest for URL - `http://www.stackoverflow.com/apps?user=me`, and this URL will get redirected to `http://www.stackoverflow2.com/`.

I want to keep the query parameters of the original URL after redirection, like `http://www.stackoverflow2.com/apps?user=me`.

The `DefaultRedirectStrategy` does not do it. It only gives me `http://www.stackoverflow2.com/`.

Is there anyway to do this decently?

Comment: Before you send your request off using the `HttpClient` why don't you just store the URL and do something like `String s[] = url.split("/");` and then you can just extract the parameters using something like that.

Comment: Then we are not taking advantage of HttpClient's RedirectStrategy. The whole thing can be customized, or I can write code by myself to handle it. But what I want is to use something in the library, and this simple method should be supported.